# Free Lindenbaum-Tarski algebra on a countable set of free generators

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, boolean-algebra

Let $V$ be a countable set of propositional variables, and $L=\{-,\vee,\wedge\}$ be a formalised language of the propositional calculus.

Let $A$ be the free Lindenbaum-Tarski algebra of formulas on the countable set of propositional variables.

Is A atomic or atomless? This is not clear for me because on one hand, $V$ is countable, but on the other hand, $L$ only consists of finitary operations.

Comment: Whenever $F$ is a formula that is not contradictory, and $A$ is a variable not appearing in $F$, what can you say about $A\land F$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say that if $\phi$ is some element, and $v$ is any variable not appearing in it (a formula only has finitely many), that $\phi \land v$ is strictly smaller than $\phi$. So no atoms.

Comment: Thanks Henno for the reply. Just one more question in passing. What is the cardinality of $A$. Is it countable? How to prove it? I know that a finitely generated Boolean algebra if finite (Corollary 2, p. 82 in Givant and Halmos). Does this result extend to the case of a BA countably generated, i.e., is a countably generated BA countable (assuming finitary operations, of course)?

Comment: $A$ is countable. There are countably many formulae using a fixed finite set of variables. And there are countably many finite subsets.

Comment: Any countable BA without atoms is isomorphic to the clopen algebra of the Cantor set.

Comment: Could you please give a little more details. Why are there countably many formulae? And why countably many finite subsets? I apologise for the trouble...

Comment: @student Another way: you build up the formulae by recursion. We start with$F_0 $: the literals: all variables, so $F_0$ is countable. Then $F_1$ is the set of $F_0 \cup \{\lnot \phi_1, \phi_1 \land \phi_2, \phi_1 \lor \phi_2: \phi_1, \phi_2 \in F_0\}$, which is countable when $F_0$ is. Similarly for $F_{n+1}$ from $F_n$. The algebra is just $\cup_n F_n$: a countable union of countable sets so countable.

Comment: Very nice explanation. Thank you very much!